# A man walks into a bank to cash a check for $d$ dollars and $c$ cents...

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A man walks into a bank to cash a check for $d$ dollars and $c$ cents.  The teller mistakenly gives him $c$ dollars and $d$ cents.  He doesn't realize the error until he has spend 23 cents.  At this point he now has $2d$ dollars and $2d$ cents.  What was the original check worth?

Here's my approach.Make two categories.   One for dollars, one for cents.
Dollars $\Rightarrow 2d=c$

Cents $\Rightarrow 2c=d-23$

However, if I solve this for either $c$ or $d$, I get a negative number ($\frac{-23}{3})$, which can't be true.

Where am I going wrong here?   I think I am supposed to use the information to set up a Diophantine Equation, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You dont have that $2d=c$ since when you spent $23$ cents it might be that the number of dollars go down.

Comment: Good point.  That makes sense.  So how do I set this up then?

Comment: Yeah. I just posted that. I think the $23$ has a wrong sign (or I might be mistaken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to keep track of money thinking of how many cents you have at any given point. If you have $a$ dollar just think that you have $100a$ in money.

You have $100c+d-23=200d+2c$, so 
$$
98c-199d=23
$$
Solve this equation now, and remember that $c$ is an integer less than $100$

Comment: i just came to this same equation, though I realized after i posted it above that I put the 23 on the wrong side originally so one was side of my equation was negated.   Now I just need to remember how to solve Diophantine Equations for the initial $x_0, y_0$